# Converting multipage PDF to TIFF does not work with Python library Wand

Tags: python, pdf, imagemagick, tiff, wand

Given the short, 5 page PDF file (attached at the bottom), and the following python code to convert to a multi-page TIFF:

```
from wand.image import Image


with Image(filename='5-page-pdf.pdf', resolution=200) as img:
    img.type = "grayscale"
    img.format = "tiff"
    img.compression = "lzw"
    img.save(filename="test.tiff")
```

results in a TIFF file that has pages 2-4 as what appears to be black text on a dark-grey (or maybe transparent) background. Other image processing libraries cannot open the file or render it.

Converting the same PDF with ImageMagick, which Wand uses, works just fine

```
convert -density 200 5-page-pdf.pdf -type grayscale -compress lzw 5-page-pdf.tiff
```

this produces a file that does work with other imaging libraries and looks correct in a TIFF viewer.

I've tried removing the alpha channel, I've tried setting the background color to 'White', and a few other things, to no avail. The TIFF that comes out of Wand is always garbled. If it's doable in ImageMagick it should be doable in Wand, right? What parameter or setting am I missing?

[Original PDF](https://moscon.org/pdf/5-page-pdf.pdf)

[Wand Produced TIFF](https://moscon.org/pdf/test.tiff)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like setting the `img.alpha_channel` property is not propagating across the pages.

Try this workaround

```py
from wand.api import library
from wand.image import Image

with Image(filename="5-page-pdf.pdf", resolution=200) as img:
    img.type = 'grayscale'
    img.compression = "lzw"
    # Manually iterate over all page, and turn off alpha channel.
    library.MagickResetIterator(img.wand)
    for idx in range(library.MagickGetNumberImages(img.wand)):
        library.MagickSetIteratorIndex(img.wand, idx)
        img.alpha_channel = 'off'
    img.save(filename="test.tiff")
```

Comment: This definitely works - thanks! Should setting the channel to off on the top level image work?

Comment: Don't think so. The internal image iterator is pointing at the end of the image-stack, so the top-level change will only be applied to the last page. This is a bug as Wand should match CLI behavior.

Comment: I had tried unsuccessfully with `for frame in img.sequence:
  img.background_color = "white"
  img.alpha_channel = "remove"`.
I also tried "off", "opaque", False.  All were unsuccessful.